# Swift dynamically assign private property without defining type

Tags: swift, types

I am having hard times trying to figure out pretty simple thing.
I have framework that only works on IOS 13+,
So when I try to initialize it with empty class like
`private var itso: ITSOFramework` I get error that ITSOFramework is only available on IOS 13+

I can add class guard, but then everything fails on run and I can run it on devices below ios13.

But all I want to do, is to have in my init method, condition to initialize it if 13+ and don't do anything below, so at least I have a app without some functionality, but at least it works.

so I am looking for something like

```swift
is #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   itso = RTDFramework.ITSOFramework()
} else{
  .. do something else
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making `itso` optional?

Comment: If i do `private var itso: ITSOFramework?` I still get error that it is only available for iOS 13+

Comment: I think I've managed it kind of with optional suggestion. But because I have alias @available(iOS 13.0, *)  on my class when I use is #available(iOS 13.0, *)  in my method which is still needed, and I get warning `Unnecessary check for iOS` why is that ? It compiles and works but why